# How to use Javascript to create custom download process and open file in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, video, progress

i am developing a website, in our website we have a Video player, and a Download button. When user click to it, it will download the video to user machine.

Usually this can be done if user right click and choose Save Video as. Then a native browser dialog open, where user can choose destination and file name, then click save. After that in the bottom of the browser there will be a widget to show progress, and user can click to open after it finishes downloading
[image]

Now my question is it possible if we create a similiar functional widget but in the website. So basically after user clicking Download. This modal will appear in the bottom left of the page

[image]

Then after downloading is finished, it will change to

[image]

**So to sum up the requirement for this**

1/ Trigger download automatically by JS without right click and choose Save video as

2/ Showing a custom progress of downloading

3/ When downloading is finished, there is a custom button, where user can click to Open

4/ [Optional] Hide the native progress/click to open widget  of the browser

So these requirement i still not sure which one is possible and which one is not, so hopefully if someone can give me a direction, thanks

Comment: If the file is stored on your server, `<a href="http://yoursite.foo/path/to/the/file" download>download</a>` is all you should need

Comment: @Kaiido but this will trigger native browser dowload UI (progress+click to open) right, cannot change to a custom one like i want

Comment: Well currently your question is asking to have "the same widget". If you want to implement a different widget, then ask for it, with the functionalities this widget should have.

Comment: @Kaiido ok maybe the wording is confusing. What i mean is to create a similiar widget, not to trigger the built-in widget, thanks

Comment: @JakeLam How big are your video files in general? This is only possible if you temporarily download bytes into a buffer (Array) first, then the buffer can be saved to disk (instant writing since already stored in memory) and buffer content can be viewed in a new tab. Is that an acceptable solution to you?